# Migrating Microsoft .NET Web Services with .NET Framework 1.1 for .NET Framework 4.7.2

Tags: .net, web-services, compatibility

If I migrate a web service with .NET Framework 1.1 or 2.0 to a newer version of framework (.NET Framework 4.7.2), will the clients (Web Sites, Consoles ...) consuming these web services continue to work? Or do I have to redo the reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asmx services are still supported in .net 4.5 (not sure about >4.5), although Microsoft recommends not to use them and to use WCF or WebApi instead.

Something that might create big issues during your migration though is if your code uses framework classes as data contracts (DataSet comes to mind...). The structure of those has changed a lot since framework 2.0 and migrating may break all your current clients.

Using such classes as data contracts has always been not advised but I've seen DataSet used as contracts in many places...